# Advanced CFontDialog

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

As you know that MFC's CFontDialog does only support int in Font size.
And if you checked MS Office you'll find that the Font Dialog supports Float font size normally.

So what is the appropriate way to implement this feature

1. Is there any implemented font dialog I may use in MFC?
2. Is there any external 3rd parity library or code?
3. Should I inherit the CFontDialog and implement the feature and is this applicable?
4. May I use a .NET dialog and call it in MFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Office doesnt use CFont Dialog. You cant use CFont dialog to support decimal numbers. Check [this](http://www.databaseforum.info/2/5/d1af32f0d64a3115.html) discussion about the same topic.

Comment: So what of the suggested solutions is the best, as I read in the discussion that they implemented a custom dialog?

Comment: @Strikerz yes you need to implement custom dialog

Answer (score 0):

1. Changed the Point size of the Font I am using to double.
2. Added a Drop Down Combobox that allow editing.
3. Handled two events for the Combo, Edit and Selection Changed.
4. It worked like charm, without creating a Dialog